# How to configure Karma to work with requirejs and qunit

Tags: javascript, requirejs, qunit, karma-runner

I'm trying to piece karma and requirejs together. but find a big issue cannot find any answer.
I have a project using requirejs and I'm using qunit as its testing framework. they work fine before karma comes in.
After following the [Karma requirejs instruction](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/plus/requirejs.html), I got an error and could not find the proper solution. The **karma version is 0.12.6**

The **error** is:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define () module ....
```

**How can I let them work together?**

here is my **files structure**

```
projectroot
    |
    |----\src
    |    |
    |    |----\demo
    |    |    |
    |    |    |----hello.js
    |    |
    |    |----\test
    |         |
    |         |----hello_test.js
    |         |----test_main.js      
    |       
    |----karma.conf.js
```

my **karma.conf.js**

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Apr 11 2014 11:43:46 GMT+0800 

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '.',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['qunit', 'requirejs'],
   //plugins:['karma-qunit','karma-launcher-chrome'], 

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/test/test-main.js',
      {pattern: 'src/demo/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'src/test/*.js', include: false}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {

    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUGs,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

my **test-main.js**

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

var pathToModule = function(path) {
  return path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/\.js$/, '');
};

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
    allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));
  }
});

console.log(allTestFiles);
require.config({
  // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
  baseUrl: '/base',

  // dynamically load all test files
  deps: allTestFiles,

  // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

my **hello_test.js**

```
define(function(){
  it("is a simple test", function(){
    ok(true, "hope it works");
    });
});
```

Thank you!

ADD the final error report screen:
[image: error screen]

You can see my hello_test.js is loaded. I read the docs about #mismatch at requirejs.org. It looks like `requirejs` cannot handle the module name when it's not loaded through their conventional way.

Comment: Is your requirejs run time configuration in hello.js?

Comment: No, hello is actually empty file. I don't `require` or `define` hello in my test. I just want to make sure they can work someway. just added my hello_test.js

Comment: try replacing  {pattern: 'src/test/*.js', include: false} with  {pattern: 'src/test/*test.js', include: false}

Comment: No difference. I update my question with an error screenshot

Comment: Someone please explain what `include: true||false` even does? Is there a location with docs for karma -- its seems the docs on the site (http://karma-runner.github.io/) totally suck on completeness...?

Answer (score 2):

**My Mistake**

two mistakes in my files:

1. misspell the `included` in karma.conf.js
2. in qunit test file.

correct qunit test case should be

```
define(function(){
    test("is a simple test", function(){
        ok(true, "hope it works");
    });
});
```

NOT `it("is a simple test", function()`...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if with your two changes you got it to work or not, but after spending about six hours fighting this same problem, I'd suggest either:

- Removing your line `{pattern: 'src/demo/*.js', included: false},`
- or, adding `'src/demo/hello.js'` to your `exclude: [ ]` array.

This was part of what caused many of my headaches.